# What would happen if i send a json file using res.send instead of res.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

We have a method res.json to send file in NodeJs but what would happen if we send a json file using res.send. What will be the consequences and why should we avoid doing this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res):

## res.json([body])

Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is **the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify()**.

The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string, Boolean, number, or null, and you can also use it to convert other values to JSON.

## res.send([body])

Sends the HTTP response.

The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array.

This method performs many useful tasks for simple non-streaming responses: For example, it automatically assigns the Content-Length HTTP response header field (unless previously defined) and provides automatic HEAD and HTTP cache freshness support.

When the parameter is a Buffer object, the method sets the Content-Type response header field to “application/octet-stream”, unless previously defined.

When the parameter is a String, the method sets the Content-Type to “text/html”.

When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the JSON representation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about ExpressJS:

Whenever an Express application server receives an HTTP request, it will provide the developer with an object, commonly referred to as res. For example,

Example

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
   // use req and res here
})
```

The res object basically refers to the response that'll be sent out as part of this API call.

## res.send:

The ***res.send*** function sets the content type to **text/Html** which means that the client will now treat it as text. It then returns the response to the client.

## res.json:

The ***res.json*** function on the other handsets the content-type header to ***application/JSON*** so that the client treats the response string as a valid JSON object. It also then returns the response to the client.

## conclusion:

With res.send you have to take care of converting it to a JSON object if needed, whereas with res.json this is done automatically.